# Is it possible to have multiple triggers in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

When you look at the summary tile on a Logic App in the Azure Portal, it says '1 trigger, x actions'

Which made me wonder is it possible to put multiple triggers in a single Logic App? or do I need to create distinct logic apps for each function (and if so, why is it telling me there's one trigger!)

On a related note (this might be better in a separate question) when using the HTTP listener, is it possible to configure multiple Relative URLs or does that need to be split out into separate Logic Apps also

Answer (score 20):

Yes, a workflow can have multiple triggers.

A workflow can have a maximum of 10 triggers and 250 actions can be defined.

You can have look on the [Workflow definition language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language) where "triggers" is an array.

NOTE: the work has to be done in the "Code" view, as the "Designer" does **NOT** support multiple triggers.

Comment: Actually the maximum number of triggers per workflow is 10 as per [Logic App limits and configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config) documentation

Comment: One drawback is that multiple triggers can't be edited from the designer.

Comment: @DavisMolinari any idea if multiple blob triggers can be used to execute the logic app? I simply wants to send an email if there is blob on dev, test or prod container. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

You can have only a single trigger per logic app.  You can test and verify this by attempting to add 2 recurrence triggers to a single logic app.  As it currently stands a Logic app is a single flow with out decision making.

Comment: I tried this before I posted, but thought I might have been missing the big (usually flashing!) button that said 'add another trigger' or some magic to be performed via code. It seems like quite an atomic component to be so high up the hierarchy, that maybe there should be a container to group them into (which perhaps the trigger count suggests is coming)

Comment: This isn't right ... each logic app CAN HAVE multiple triggers